# MagicalRecord not functioning properly

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, magicalrecord

I'm developing a game and I'm using MagicalRecord to store high scores. The game has 4 modes and 2 "types" and so 8 combinations are available each of which I would like to store a high score for. I'm using this logic:

```
NSArray *arrayOfHighscores = [Highscores MR_findAll];
if([arrayOfHighscores count] == 0) {
    Highscores *highScores = [Highscores MR_createEntity];

    highScores.normalTapHighscore = [NSNumber numberWithInt:0];
    highScores.normalSwipeHighscore = [NSNumber numberWithInt:0];
    highScores.zenTapHighscore = [NSNumber numberWithInt:0];
    highScores.zenSwipeHighscore = [NSNumber numberWithInt:0];
    highScores.crazyTapHighscore = [NSNumber numberWithInt:0];
    highScores.crazySwipeHighscore = [NSNumber numberWithInt:0];
    highScores.endlessTapHighscore = [NSNumber numberWithInt:0];
    highScores.endlessSwipeHighscore = [NSNumber numberWithInt:0];

    [[NSManagedObjectContext MR_contextForCurrentThread] MR_saveToPersistentStoreAndWait];
}
Highscores *highScores = [Highscores MR_findFirst/*:[NSManagedObjectContext MR_contextForCurrentThread]*/];

if (currentGameMode == NORMAL_GAME_MODE) {
    if (currentGameType == TAP_GAME_TYPE) {
        if (score > (int)highScores.normalTapHighscore) {
            highScore = score;
            highScores.normalTapHighscore = [NSNumber numberWithInt:score];
            [[NSManagedObjectContext MR_contextForCurrentThread] MR_saveToPersistentStoreAndWait];
        } else highScore = (int)highScores.normalTapHighscore;
    } else {
        if (score > (int)highScores.normalSwipeHighscore) {
            highScore = score;
            highScores.normalSwipeHighscore = [NSNumber numberWithInt:score];
            [[NSManagedObjectContext MR_contextForCurrentThread] MR_saveToPersistentStoreAndWait];
        } else highScore = (int)highScores.normalSwipeHighscore;
    }
} else if (currentGameMode == ZEN_GAME_MODE) {
    if (currentGameType == TAP_GAME_TYPE) {
        if (score > (int)highScores.zenTapHighscore) {
            highScore = score;
            highScores.zenTapHighscore = [NSNumber numberWithInt:score];
            [[NSManagedObjectContext MR_contextForCurrentThread] MR_saveToPersistentStoreAndWait];
        } else highScore = (int)highScores.zenTapHighscore;
    } else {
        if (score > (int)highScores.zenSwipeHighscore) {
            highScore = score;
            highScores.zenSwipeHighscore = [NSNumber numberWithInt:score];
            [[NSManagedObjectContext MR_contextForCurrentThread] MR_saveToPersistentStoreAndWait];
        } else highScore = (int)highScores.zenSwipeHighscore;
    }
} else if (currentGameMode == CRAZY_GAME_MODE) {
    if (currentGameType == TAP_GAME_TYPE) {
        if (score > (int)highScores.crazyTapHighscore) {
            highScore = score;
            [highScores setCrazyTapHighscore:[NSNumber numberWithInt:score]];
            [[NSManagedObjectContext MR_contextForCurrentThread] MR_saveToPersistentStoreAndWait];
        } else highScore = (int)highScores.crazyTapHighscore;
    } else {
        if (score > (int)highScores.crazySwipeHighscore) {
            highScore = score;
            [highScores setCrazySwipeHighscore:[NSNumber numberWithInt:score]];
            [[NSManagedObjectContext MR_contextForCurrentThread] MR_saveToPersistentStoreAndWait];
        } else highScore = (int)highScores.crazySwipeHighscore;
    }
} else if (currentGameMode == ENDLESS_GAME_MODE) {
    if (currentGameType == TAP_GAME_TYPE) {
        if (score > (int)highScores.endlessTapHighscore) {
            highScore = score;
            highScores.endlessTapHighscore = [NSNumber numberWithInt:score];
            [[NSManagedObjectContext MR_contextForCurrentThread] MR_saveToPersistentStoreAndWait];
        } else highScore = (int)highScores.endlessTapHighscore;
    } else {
        if (score > (int)highScores.endlessSwipeHighscore) {
            highScore = score;
            highScores.endlessSwipeHighscore = [NSNumber numberWithInt:score];
            [[NSManagedObjectContext MR_contextForCurrentThread] MR_saveToPersistentStoreAndWait];
        } else highScore = (int)highScores.endlessSwipeHighscore;
    }
}
```

and the `highscore` variable is being displayed on the screen. Also for testing purposes I'm calling `MR_truncateAll` at the beginning of the program.

Here's the problem: the first time I play and the game ends displaying the game over view, my current score is displayed. Though, the second time, a 3-digit number appears on the screen (even though my score was lesser than the first time). I tried debugging and all that, it seems in the second time, the `highScores` object contains: `data: <fault>`.

What should I do? Tell me if you need anymore details.. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're not understanding the difference between NSNumbers and primitive integer types.

When you have your highscores (managed) object saving all your data, you need to store everything in an NSNumber. But you can't just cast it back to an (int) type. What you're getting there is likely the address of that NSNumber object. Instead, you should use **[highScores.endlessSwipeHighScore integerValue]** to get the proper primitive type value to use in your logic.

Comment: Actually, `[highScores.endlessSwipeHighScore integerValue]` also returns an NSNumber, though `intValue` doesn't! It worked perfectly. Thanks for a quick answer!